# How can I find the asset allocation of the FTSE All-World Index?

Tags: etf, market-indexes, asset-allocation

I am trying to find the asset allocation of Vanguard's FTSE All-World ETF. Even though Vanguard's documents preciselly state ETFs holdings in percentage, I have not found the asset allocation in terms of emerging markets, european stocks, small caps...

Since the ETF tracks the FTSE All-World Index, I have tried to find the information regarding this index, but I have been unable to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The ETF

On the [Portfolio Data](https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/investments/vanguard-ftse-all-world-ucits-etf-usd-distributing/portfolio-data) page you can find statistics about:

- Region exposure:
  [image: VWRL region exposure]
- Market exposure:
  [image: VWRL market allocation]
- Industry exposure:
  [image: VWRL industry exposure]

The list of all Vanguard FTSE All-World UCITS ETF holdings (security name, number of shares, percentage weight) is available starting on page 31 of Vanguard Funds plc's [2019 annual report](https://www.vanguardinvestor.co.uk/rs/gre/gls/1.3.0/documents/959/gb). The list is grouped by market (Australia, Austria, Belgium, Brazil, ...). The percentage allocation by market is also given.

### The index

The Vanguard FTSE All-World UCITS ETF aims to track the FTSE All-World Index. For information about the index itself:

- [FTSE Global Equity Index Series (GEIS)](https://www.ftserussell.com/products/indices/geisac):

  - [FTSE All-World Index factsheet](https://research.ftserussell.com/Analytics/FactSheets/Home/DownloadSingleIssue?openfile=open&issueName=AWORLDS&isManual=False)
  - Look into the methodology PDFs
- [Constituents & Weights](https://www.ftserussell.com/analytics/factsheets/home/constituentsweights)

  - [FTSE All-World Index constituents](https://research.ftserussell.com/analytics/factsheets/Home/DownloadConstituentsWeights/?indexdetails=AWORLDS)

Comment: Thank you. Is this asset allocation also a target? i.e. will they rebalance based to keep e.g. exposure to pacific region around 12.6%?

Comment: @D1X The ETF is supposed to track the index, so the asset allocation of the ETF depends on the allocation in the index. The allocations in the index depends on the index methodology.